# Regex para pegar sequência de letras ou números

Tags: php, regex

Tenho um site em que faço um monte de embed do youtube, aí pra facilitar pensei em usar `{youtube 54sd3}` por exemplo, e na hora de imprimir o resultado ele substituri por:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/54sd3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Achei essa solução, mas só funciona com número, qual a regex para aceitar todos os caracteres?

```
$content='{youtube 123}';
$pattern = '#\{youtube ([0-9][a-Z]+)\}#i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

A sua regex estava pegando apenas um número (`[0-9]`) seguido de uma ou mais letras. Com o detalhe que `[a-Z]` (com o "Z" maiúsculo) dá erro, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/7fDjv6/1/).

Enfim, se quer que tenha letras ou números, basta usar uma única [classe de caracteres](https://regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) com ambos os intervalos: `[0-9a-z]` (repare que coloquei o "z" minúsculo). Como você usou a [*flag*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `i`, a regex já vai considerar tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minúsculas (se só quiser minúsculas, retire o `i` do final do *pattern*).

Enfim, para extrair os trechos que tem `{youtube blablabla}` e transformar na *tag* desejada:

```
$content='texto {youtube 123} blablabla {youtube 54sd3} xyz';
$pattern = '#\{youtube ([0-9a-z]+)\}#i';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $valor) {
        echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{$valor}\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/123" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/54sd3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Ou, se quiser fazer a substituição direto na própria string:

```
echo preg_replace('#\{youtube ([0-9a-z]+)\}#i',
    '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
    $content);
```

Saída:

```
texto <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/123" frameborder="0"></iframe> blablabla <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/54sd3" frameborder="0"></iframe> xyz
```

Em ambos os casos coloquei o trecho correspondente ao código entre parênteses, pois aí forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Com isso, esse trecho fica disponível em `$matches[1]` (no caso do `preg_match_all`) e em `$1` (no caso do `preg_replace`) - pois como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então corresponde ao grupo 1.

Outro detalhe é que, como a regex é *case insensitive*, ela também aceita casos como `{YOUTube abCD123}`. Se quer que o texto "youtube" esteja sempre em minúsculas e somente o código possa ter maiúsculas e minúsculas, você deve retirar a *flag* `i` e adicionar as letras maiúsculas, ficando então `'#\{youtube ([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\}#'`.

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445933/112052) sugeriu usar ponto, só que há um problema: a regex pode acabar pegando mais caracteres do que o desejado, já que o [ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere](https://regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (inclusive o `}`, espaços, etc). Ou seja, se eu fizer:

```
$content='texto {youtube 123} blablabla {youtube 54sd3} xyz';
$pattern = '#\{youtube (.+)\}#i';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $valor) {
        echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{$valor}\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

O resultado será:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/123} blablabla {youtube 54sd3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Repare que dentro do `src` foi colocado todo o conteúdo entre o `123` até o último `}`. Isso porque o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (qualquer um, inclusive o `}`), e os quantificadores como o `+` são ["gananciosos"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) e pegam a maior quantidade possível de caracteres (por isso ele pega mais do que "devia").

Só que nesse caso você não quer "qualquer caractere", e sim "uma sequência de letras e números", por isso é melhor [ser mais específico](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) e colocar na regex exatamente aquilo que você quer.

Answer (score -1):

Não vou abordar se está pratica é a melhor, ou se esta correta.

Respondendo a pergunta:

> Qual a regex para aceitar todos os caracteres?

```
.   Curinga: corresponde a qualquer caractere único, exceto \n.
```

Font: [Linguagem de expressões regulares – referência rápida](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Pensando na expressão fornecida: `{youtube 54sd3}`

Podemos usar, levando em consideração, que a expressão leva 1 ou mais caracteres apos `youtube`:

```
[{youtube ]{9}.+[}]{1}
```

Para testar: [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Só uma coisa, quando você coloca algo entre colchetes, como `[{youtube ]`, está dizendo que na verdade você quer qualquer caractere dentre os que estão nos colchetes (e ao colocar `{9}`, não necessariamente os 9 caracteres precisam estar na ordem em que aparecem), ou seja, sua regex aceita coisas como `yyyy{{{ bb_}` - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/1Ms3jU/2/). Outro detalhe é que `{1}` é redundante, `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`. E tem outros problemas em usar `.+`, que explico melhor na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445945/112052) :-)